# How can I use ReflectionToStringBuilder and format Dates as readable Strings?

Tags: java, date, formatting, apache-commons, date-formatting

I have a `toString` method implemented as written below:

```
public String toString() {
    return new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this, new MultilineRecursiveToStringStyle()).toString();
}
```

This works well but Timestamps (and, I assume, Dates) are shown as a plain toString on the Object would show:

```
changeTime=java.sql.Timestamp@32a9d65c[
  nanos=0
],
```

Is there any way to tell `ReflectionToStringBuilder` how I would like Date objects formatted?

Comment: Did you read the Javadoc? There are callbacks you can use to control the formatting of every accessible field.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. `ReflectionToStringBuilder` allows that:

```
new ReflectionToStringBuilder(this) {
   @Override
   protected Object getValue(Field field) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
     if (Timestamp.class.equals(field.getType())) {
       return "convert timestamp to String";
     } else {
       return super.getValue(field);
     }
   }
}
```